# Scrape arraytodatatable with python

Tags: python, regex, web-scraping

I'm working on scraping data from [this](http://www.forecasts.org/data/data/PAYEMS.htm) page, specifically the "Statistics Table For All Employees".

When I try to use `BeautifulSoup` or a simple regex, I am unable to pull the table, presumably either because it is a nested list or because of the line breaks, although I really have no clue.

Here's some sample code:

```
url='http://www.forecasts.org/data/data/PAYEMS.htm'

def get( URL): #getting text from the web
    ses = requests.session()
    return ses.get(URL).text 

htmltext=get(url)

regex = 'Date(.+?)All' 
pattern = re.compile(regex)
nonFarm = re.findall(pattern,htmltext)
```

[image]

Desired output:

```
[1939-01-01, 29923, 1939-02-01, 30101, ...]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the desired data is inside a javascript code.

I would use regular expressions to parse the javascript array and [`literal_eval()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) to "load" it into a Python list:

```
from ast import literal_eval
from pprint import pprint
import re

import requests


url = 'http://www.forecasts.org/data/data/PAYEMS.htm'
with requests.Session() as session:
    response = session.get(url)

    pattern = re.compile(r"data = google\.visualization\.arrayToDataTable\((.*?)\);", re.MULTILINE | re.DOTALL)
    data = pattern.search(response.content).group(1)

    data = literal_eval(data)
    pprint(data)
```

Prints:

```
[['Date', 'All Employees: Total nonfarm'],
 ['1939-01-01', 29923],
 ['1939-02-01', 30101],
 ...
 ['2014-07-01', 138976],
 ['2014-08-01', 139118]]
```